# IndexOutOfBoundsException with Android ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got a very annoying problem with some code throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException and I really cannot understand why. The logcat points to the "addTimetableItem" of the following code which ill explain more on:

```
if(sortedFridayTimes.size()>0){
    insertDay("Friday");
    for(int i=1; i<sortedFridayTimes.size()+1;i++){
        addTimetableItem(sortedFridayTimes.get(i));
    }
}
```

"sortedFridayTimes" is an ArrayList containing my own "Timetable Entry" objects which I have sorted into order already. First the size is checked to see if there are any objects and if there is then "insertDay" runs which creates a new textview for a title and adds it to the layout (This works fine..).
Inside the for loop the idea is to then add all the objects from the arraylist into the layout. Now I know that the "addTimetableItem" code works as ive tested it already, but my problem is that i cant seem to get the last object out of the arraylist. If I declare the for loop to only run for

```
"i<sortedFridayTimes.size()"
```

then the program runs fine but I don't get the last entry in the arraylist which I know exists because I've debugged and watched my variables. On adding the "+1" as shown above I now get the IndexOutOfBoundsException and I really don't know why. As I've said, I've debugged and I know that an entry exists in the arraylist where I'm trying to point to, but it just crashes. I can provide more code if needs be, but does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i<sortedFridayTimes.size()+1
```

You are looping past the last element in the array. Why the `+1`?

If there are `N` elements in the array, then the elements are from indexes `0` through to `N-1`.

So it should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<sortedFridayTimes.size(); i++) {
```

Comment: Well I thought that but if say the size was 2, i would start at 1 and would be less than 2 and therefore the code would execute, but then i would become 2 which isnt less than 2 and therefore the code wouldnt run and i would miss the 2nd value in the list..right?

Comment: Cheers for the help, sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

You should accept @Tim's or @Graham's answer, this is just an addendum.  They're correct about your `size()+1` going past the end of the array.

If you're having difficulty using indexes to properly get everything out of the list, you can also try using a for-each loop (depending on the version of the Android SDK you're using).  I'm assuming `sortedFridayTimes` is a list of class `TimetableItem` since you don't specify.

So this:

```
if(sortedFridayTimes.size()>0){
    insertDay("Friday");
    for(int i=1; i<sortedFridayTimes.size()+1;i++){
        addTimetableItem(sortedFridayTimes.get(i));
    }
}
```

Becomes this:

```
if(!sortedFridayTimes.isEmtpy()){
    insertDay("Friday");
    for(TimetimeItem item : sortedFridayTimes){
        addTimetableItem(item);
    }
}
```

A little cleaner if you don't actually need to use `i` anywhere.

Comment: Android best practice also recommends using the enhanced for loop for more efficient programs. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last loop in your for loop runs:

`sortedFridayTimes.get(sortedFridayTimes.size())`

This will always be out of bounds, because the elements are zero indexed.

For example, if the array size is "5", then you cannot access index "5", because the 5 elements in the array are `0,1,2,3,4`.

Comment: I thought with an ArrayList the index began at 1?

Comment: Ok cheers, bit stupid really and I dont know why I thought that it was 1, loosing my head here! Anyway, tested and working, thanks again.

Comment: @Josh Make sure you click the `accept` checkmark on this answer if it's the one that solved your problem.